# Help on old bathroom tiles falling and crumbling

Tags: bathroom, grout, old-house, ceramic-tile

I recently had to make some small renovations in my very old bathroom, which made me realize the tiles on the walls are in a very bad shape. I think they are original from the 1940 house build, and the grout is crumbling away very easily. I had to remove a few tiles for an outlet, and just scraping away the grout made some of them fall off. They seem to only be spot glued to a plywood backing.

What would you guys recommend I do in this case? I quite like the tiles, I do have the budget for a replacement but I am currently lacking time to redo everything. Could I just scrape the grout, glue back the tiles that fell off, and put on fresh new grout? The plywood backing is surprisingly sane, no signs of mold or bad smell anywhere in the bathroom.

And if I was to replace all the tiling, should I replace the plywood backing? It does not feel very stiff, would it be easier to place larger or smaller tiles on this sort of backing?

Answer (score 1):

It is not uncommon on the older homes, (30yrs +) for the mastic that held tiles on to get dry and lose their holding power. Then the tiles fall off at the first disturbance.

It's your home, you can do as you wish.  If you are ok with reapplying the tiles and regrouting, go for it.  I would recommend an [Acrylic Mastic](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-AcrylPro-4-qt-Professional-Ceramic-Tile-72-Hr-Dry-Time-Tile-Adhesive-ARL40001/100015587?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060400-92700076247463652&gclid=Cj0KCQjwnrmlBhDHARIsADJ5b_ktVQ2GtDb7RtWbT719HLk95vi1JOWG1KgaXuT63CUr3kd88N-8UmYaAmjoEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) if the tile is not in a shower or tub area where it will be getting wet regularly.
If it is in a wet area use a modified thin set.

It is difficult for us to determine if you should replace the plywood backer.
we cannot see it, but you describe it as in good shape, but not very stiff. That still leaves it open to interpretation.

Comment: Yeah, might be worth just going ahead and retiling using modern methods.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming you own the home, if not you need to consult your landlord. If you are going to do it, be sure to comply with your local code. You can check with your local building department for a proper answer. At that point you can determine if a permit is required. They will also tell you what they would approve and what they wouldn't. You do not want to install it then have to remove it and redo.

Comment: What kind of permit is anyone going to need to stick some tiles back on a wall? This doesn't even begin to answer the question.

Comment: Tiling does not require a permit.

Comment: No permit required that's for sure. And I'm the owner of the house obviously, or else I would not give a damn that the tile is falling apart.